# Drupal installed via composer generating memory errors

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8

I've taken over an existing Drupal project, I've cloned the git repository of the project onto a development server, and ran `composer install` to install all project dependencies.

When I try to view the website in my browser, I see an error 500 and the apache error logs on the server are showing the following error;

```
[Mon Jan 14 11:38:41.246259 2019] [php7:error] [pid 1363] [client 80.229.235.74:52957] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73728 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/agilit-e/6bc72c45/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
```

I've increased the available RAM on the server to 3GB, and I've edited my php.ini file to increase available memory to 2GB (confirmed via phpinfo()), but I'm still seeing this error.

Is there any reason why Composer requires so much memory? Here's a copy of my composer.json file for reference.

```
{
  "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
  "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-2.0+",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "role": ""
    }
  ],
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "harvesthq/chosen",
        "version": "1.6.1",
        "type": "drupal-library",
        "dist": {
          "url": "https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/download/v1.6.1/chosen_v1.6.1.zip",
          "type": "zip"
        },
        "require": {
          "composer/installers": "^1.2.0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "dinbror/blazy",
        "version": "1.8.2",
        "type": "drupal-library",
        "dist": {
          "url": "https://github.com/dinbror/blazy/archive/1.8.2.zip",
          "type": "zip"
        },
        "require": {
          "composer/installers": "^1.2.0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://gitlab.com/leed-collective/capita-cs-base-theme.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://gitlab.com/leed-collective/capita-cs-admin-theme.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://gitlab.com/leed-collective/capita-cs-base-modules.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
    "dinbror/blazy": "^1.8",
    "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.2",
    "drupal/access_unpublished": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.19",
    "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.1",
    "drupal/autocomplete_deluxe": "^1.0",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^3.0",
    "drupal/blazy": "^1.0",
    "drupal/block_class": "^1.0",
    "drupal/block_content_permissions": "^1.0",
    "drupal/chosen": "^2.3",
    "drupal/config_filter": "^1.0",
    "drupal/config_ignore": "^2.1",
    "drupal/config_split": "^1.2",
    "drupal/console": "~1.0",
    "drupal/core": "~8.5.8",
    "drupal/ctools": "^3.0",
    "drupal/default_content": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/devel": "^1.0",
    "drupal/diff": "^1.0",
    "drupal/draggableviews": "^1.0",
    "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^1.6",
    "drupal/entity_browser": "^1.0",
    "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.3",
    "drupal/eu_cookie_compliance": "^1.0",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.0",
    "drupal/formblock": "^1.0",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^2.1",
    "drupal/google_tag": "^1.0",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^1.23",
    "drupal/image_style_quality": "^1.3",
    "drupal/image_widget_crop": "^2.0",
    "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0",
    "drupal/ip2country": "^1.8",
    "drupal/link_attributes": "^1.1",
    "drupal/linkit": "^5.0",
    "drupal/media_entity_document": "1.1",
    "drupal/media_entity_image": "1.2",
    "drupal/media_entity_video": "1.0-beta2",
    "drupal/menu_block": "^1.4",
    "drupal/menu_breadcrumb": "^1.3",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.3",
    "drupal/migrate_plus": "^2.0",
    "drupal/migrate_tools": "^2.0",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.1",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.0",
    "drupal/pathologic": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/rabbit_hole": "^1.0",
    "drupal/recreate_block_content": "^2.0",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.0",
    "drupal/restrict_ip": "^1.3",
    "drupal/search_exclude": "^1.1",
    "drupal/search_exclude_nid": "^1.2",
    "drupal/signature": "dev-1.x#048ad876778b2e1ad5a3baaabd2210e1e1be7a1e",
    "drupal/silent_contribute": "^1.1",
    "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^2.7",
    "drupal/smtp": "^1.0",
    "drupal/social_media_links": "^2.4",
    "drupal/styleguide": "^1.0",
    "drupal/taxonomy_access_fix": "^2.5",
    "drupal/token": "^1.0",
    "drupal/token_filter": "^1.0",
    "drupal/twig_tweak": "^1.8",
    "drupal/username_enumeration_prevention": "^1.0",
    "drupal/video_embed_field": "^1.5",
    "drupal/video_embed_wistia": "^1.0",
    "drupal/views_bulk_edit": "^1.0",
    "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^1.0",
    "drupal/webform": "5.0-rc11",
    "drush/drush": "~8.0",
    "leed-collective/capita_base_theme": "master",
    "leed-collective/capita_admin_theme": "master",
    "leed-collective/capita-cs-base-modules": "master",
    "geerlingguy/drupal-vm": "4.7.0",
    "harvesthq/chosen": "^1.6",
    "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^1.1",
    "webflo/drupal-finder": "^0.3.0",
    "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "behat/mink": "~1.7",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.2",
    "jcalderonzumba/gastonjs": "~1.0.2",
    "jcalderonzumba/mink-phantomjs-driver": "~0.3.1",
    "mikey179/vfsstream": "~1.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": ">=4.8.28 <5",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~2.8"
  },
  "conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "scripts": {
      "drupal-scaffold": "DrupalComposer\\DrupalScaffold\\Plugin::scaffold",
      "pre-install-cmd": [
          "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
      ],
      "pre-update-cmd": [
          "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
      ],
      "post-install-cmd": [
          "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
      ],
      "post-update-cmd": [
          "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
      ]
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-types": [
        "capita-module",
        "capita-theme",
        "capita-profile"
    ],
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "web/libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "web/modules/capita_base/{$name}": [
            "type:capita-module"
        ],
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "web/profiles/capita_base/{$name}": [
            "type:capita-profile"
        ],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "web/themes/capita_base/{$name}": [
            "type:capita-theme"
        ],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ]
    },
    "patches": {
      "drupal/core": {
        "Fix issue of grouped filters using the array key id for the query rather than the term IDs": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2049603-fixing-tid-in-exposed-group-filter-sql-query-in-views.patch"
      },
      "drupal/default_content": {
        "Allow exporting all taxonomy terms for a given vocab": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/default_content-export-all-items-2786479-12.patch",
        "Allow existing entities to be updated": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-06-05/default_content-dont-reimport-existing-entities-2698425-102.patch",
        "Allow manually importing content again, not just on install": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/default_content-allow_manual_imports-2640734-72.patch"
      },
      "drupal/field_group": {
        "Tabs with invalid input are not focused": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/field-group-tab-focus-invalid-input.patch"
      },
      "drupal/linkit": {
        "Linkit for Link field": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-03-25/2712951-59.patch"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 2097152 bytes is about 2 megabytes - it is extremely low limit for project of this size. You should check again your PHP config - error should be different if you really change memory limit to 2 GB.

Comment: You're right, I had se the limit to 2000MB rather than 2000M.